# Using elance gem "get_access_token" method is not return access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have integrating Elance API in rails project using **'elance' gem** then I used inbuilt methods for authentication and get access token.

here lib/elance/authentication.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'curb'
require "base64"
require 'uri'

module Elance
 class Authentication
  @@authorize_url = "https://api.elance.com/api2/oauth/authorize"
  @@access_token_url = "https://api.elance.com/api2/oauth/token"

  def initialize(client_id, client_secret)
    @client_id = client_id
    @client_secret = client_secret
    @curl_headers = []
    @response_code = 0
  end

  def request_access_code(redirect_url)
    @@authorize_url + "?client_id=" + @client_id + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + redirect_url
  end

  def init_curl(url)
    c = Curl::Easy.new( url )
    c.set(:ENCODING, 1)
    c.set(:SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
    c.set(:CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
    c
  end

  def get_access_token(auth_code)
    c = self.init_curl( @@access_token_url )
    c.headers['Authorization'] = "Basic "+ Base64.encode64(@client_id + ":" + @client_secret)
    c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('code', URI.escape(auth_code)),
                    Curl::PostField.content('grant_type', 'authorization_code'))
    res = c.perform
    ap res
    res
  end

  def exec_request(url, access_token)
    c = self.init_curl( url )
    c.headers['Authorization'] = "Basic "+ access_token
    c.perform
    c.body_str
  end
end
end
```

In above file get_access_token method is not returning token it gives error Undefined method "ap" when i commented line then always return true. and I pass parameter as auth_code which is getting from request_access_code method.

I used rails 4.0.4, ruby 2.1.1

so, I need some help for doing this stuff and move next.

please let me know

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `ap` method comes from [the awesome_print gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/awesome_print).  If we look at the runtime dependencies for [the elance gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/elance), we see that awesome_print isn't listed, so it wasn't installed automatically when you included the elance gem in your Gemfile.  However, it used to be; [this commit](https://github.com/NetVersaLLC/elance_gem/commit/9d80c7dc95f1054942f67a83b7a96c1e8b299793) on the elance project shows where awesome_print was removed as a dependency. In the code above it looks like they didn't remove all the awesome_print method calls when the dependency was removed.

I would file an issue on the elance project to get this fixed.  In the meantime, if you don't want to comment out the offending line, you can try including the awesome_print gem in your Gemfile.

Comment: Many Thnx for your suggestion, I added 'awesome_gem' then error removed. but why it will return true response instead of access token.